# Proprietary codecs on Linux. What is legal?

Tags: ffmpeg, vlc, codec

So, assuming we got a distribution without proprietary codecs installed.
Let's take Linux Mint for example. I want to store and playback wav and ogg format sounds, either by using my own software, or by using another developer's software. So far so good right?

Imagine now that we have the following scenario. For some reason, I wanna playback a file that is either an mp4 or mp3 or mpeg or any other format, made by proprietary codecs. Instantly, I will need a codec for these formats.

I read somewhere that Fluendo sells solutions for "legal codec usage" for linux distros.
URL of fluendo: http://www.fluendo.com/en/

So here comes the questions:

Using VLC and ffmpeg is enough for me to convert a file to an ogg or ogv so I can playback a song or a video using an open format. You can also playback playback files made by proprietary formats. But are VLC and ffmpeg legal to use, to playback such files made by proprietary codecs? For example, ss VLC codecs okay to be used without paying anyone for mp4 playback? Is it okay to convert a file from mp4 to ogv? 
If not, are there any legal and open source and free (as in freedom) codecs around that can solve the issue, or does someone have to pay a product, to be ethically correct, to the developers of the proprietaty codecs?

Note that I do not ask for Windows, since codec licenses are included to the price of the operating system. I ask exclusively for a free linux distribution.

Comment: This isn't really a programming question, thus it's off-topic for this site.  It also uses the [tag:free] tag incorrectly.

Comment: Oh, sorry about using "free" tag wrong, I am new to Stack Overflow, so excuse my mistake. Fixed it.
This probably seems not related on programming, but it actually might be related, if someone has a free open source solution to this or if someone actually knows the answer.
So please excuse me for letting this question alive, if it won't get answered in the next 48 hours I will probably request a delete or something.
But till then please give people who might be helpful a chance to reach me.

Comment: Restated the question to clarify some things.

Comment: See [FFmpeg License and Legal Considerations: Patent Mini-FAQ](https://ffmpeg.org/legal.html).

Comment: @LordNeckbeard thank you. It clarifies a lot and states we should be aware of such patents. Furthermore research on this topic is probably gonna become a legal issue, thus out of topic. So I am satisfied with this. P.S. I can't believe I missed that.
It seem that mpeg technologies are really an issue, so we should be careful about it, especially when applying installation of distros for commercial use for a company. That was what I wanted to know. So we should be careful what we use. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Since @LordNeckbeard pointed me to the FAQ of FFmpeg, that I really can't believe I missed, it became clear to me that there is a problem in using proprietary codecs, thus there are some file formats that could be avoided to keep ourselves safe. Otherwise if someone can afford a license to use them too, that would be perfectly fine.
So mp3, mp4, mpeg and some more patented formats are to be avoided, if not licensed.
ffmpeg can be built so it can exclude support for such formats and if you need to use sound or video to your software ogg and ogv are nice and efficient formats as we all know.

Digging a little deeper Ι found that too.

https://www.fsf.org/resources/playogg_radiostation.pdf